# How to provide options across many commands with node.js commander

Tags: node.js, node-commander

**The Situation**

I provide many commands, like this:

```
program
  .command('foo-command')
  .description('Do foo things')
  .option('-s, --staging', 'Tells the system to use the staging instance')
  .option('-c, --certroot <path>', 'Path to the certoot')
  .action(function(optional) {
    //do foo things
  });

program
    .command('bar-command')
    .description('Do bar things')
    .option('-s, --staging', 'Tells the system to use the staging instance')
    .option('-c, --certroot <path>', 'Path to the certoot')
    .action(function(optional) {
      //do bar things
    });
```

**The Problem**

Notice I have to repeat my option declarations. I have many options and this creates repetition.

Also, these options won't show up in my -h "help" output:

```
 Usage: cert_manager [options] [command]


  Commands:

    generate   Any CMS websites without an SSL cert will have a cert created and it will be uploaded to our CDN
    renew      Any SSL cert that is about to expire will be renewed and re-uploaded to our CDN

  Options:

    -h, --help  output usage information
```

**The Question**

How Can I declare options only once, have them apply to all commands, and have them show up in the -h help?

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer!

You can also specify options on the program object:

```
 program
  .command('foo-command')
  .description('Do foo things')
  .action(function(optional) {
    //do foo things
  });

program
    .command('bar-command')
    .description('Do bar things')
    .action(function(optional) {
      //do bar things
    });

program.option('-c, --certroot <path>' , 'Options for all commands').parse(process.argv)
```