# In Node Commander how to render all options for a command if it's options are not passed?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, node-commander

In [Commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#readme) if the CLI is ran without specifying a command I get something like:

```
Options:
  -h, --help      display help for command

Commands:
  foo [options]  Foo
  bar [options]   Bar
  help [command]  display help for command
```

but if I run the CLI as:

```
app foo
```

I'd like to return all available options for that sole command.

### Code

```
const foo = () => {
  program
    .command('foo')
    .description('This is a foo')
    .option('-a, --alpha [string]', 'Show Alpha', false)
    .option('-b, --beta [string]', 'Show Beta', false)
    .action(async options => {
      clear()
      try {
        const { alpha, beta } = options
        if (alpha === false && beta === false) return program.help()
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(chalk.red('Error: '), chalk.white(e.message))
        return process.exit(1)
      }
    })
}

export default foo
```

However `program.help()` doesn't specify the command's options but shows the output like in the first example.

### Research

- [Get multiple command option using commander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567667/get-multiple-command-option-using-commander)
- [Commander.js display help when called with no commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336656/commander-js-display-help-when-called-with-no-commands)
- [NodeJS, Commander - How to identify if user has passed un-supported option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588884/nodejs-commander-how-to-identify-if-user-has-passed-un-supported-option)
- [How to provide options across many commands with node.js commander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865188/how-to-provide-options-across-many-commands-with-node-js-commander)
- [Commander.js - Implementing sub commands that executes when the previous one is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577261/commander-js-implementing-sub-commands-that-executes-when-the-previous-one-is)
- [How to process options before commands in commander.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694836/how-to-process-options-before-commands-in-commander-js)
- [Node.js commander with optional+variadic arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022700/node-js-commander-with-optionalvariadic-arguments)

In Commander how to return `options` for a command if no `option` is passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the help for the subcommand, you use the subcommand to display the help. The action handler is passed the command to make this easy from an  arrow function.

```
    .action(async (options, cmd) => {
       // ...
       cmd.help();
       }
```

(Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Commander.)